# Proving Convergent Series made by continuous function $f$, $a_n=f(1/n)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $f$ is continuous on an interval around 0, and let $a_n=f(1/n)$

Prove that if $f''(0)$ exists and $f(0)=f'(0)=0$, then $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}}$ converges.

This is problem from Spivak calculus 4th, chapter 23 Exercise 6.

If "$f''(0)$ exists" were missing, $a_n=\frac{1}{n\log{n}}$ is a counterexample.

Its reverse also false. $a_n=\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Differentiate $a_n$ with respect to $n$.

Comment: clearly by Taylor's theorem $a_{n} = f(1/n) = (f''(0) + \rho)/2n^{2}$ where $\rho$ tends to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. Now compare with $\sum(1/n^{2})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existence of the second derivative at $0$ implies that there exists $k,\delta>0$ such that
$$
|f'(x)|\leq kx,\ \ \ x\in[0,\delta)
$$
(just take $\varepsilon=1$, $k=f''(0)+1$, and use that $\lim_{x\to0}f'(x)/x=f''(0)$).

By the Mean Value Theorem,
$$
f(x)=f'(\xi)\,x,
$$
for some $\xi\in(0,x)$. So, for $x\in[0,\delta)$, 
$$
|f(x)|\leq kx^2.
$$ 
Now, if $N>1/\delta$,$$
\sum_{n>N}|f\left(\frac1n\right)|\leq\sum_{n>N}\frac k{n^2}<\infty.
$$