spivak chapter 22 (3ed.)-Problem 6-section e
i'm strugling with this:
Let f(x) be a continuous function on an interval containing the number 0, and let a(n)=f(1/n) (for n sufficiently large).
e) suppose $f(0)=f'(0)=0$ .... Should  $\sum(a(n))$ converge?
NOTE: nothing is said about $f''(x)$ so  this article
Proving Convergent Series made by continuous function $f$, $a_n=f(1/n)$
is not valid.
#########################
I think it does, if a(n)>0.
My demo (but I'm not sure if it's ok) is like this (I'm not going to be very strict):

$f'(0)=0$ => $N|f(1/N)| < epsilon1$ , N large.

$\sum(a(n))$ converge <=>  $| f(1/N) + f(1/(N+1)) + .... + f(1/M) | < epsilon2$  (for N,M large, M>N)


And now the demo:
(this steps is true if f(1/n) is positive)
$
| f(1/N) + f(1/N+1) + .... + f(1/M) | < | N*f(1/N) + (N+1)*f(1/N+1) + .... + M*f(1/M) | 
$
each is minor than epsilon1 (asumption 1):
$
N*f(1/N) < epsilon1
(N+1)*f(1/(N+1)) < epsilon1
$
...
so naming:
epsilon1=epsilon2/(M-N)
we can continue the inequality at the right:
(...) < (M-N)* epsilon2/(M-N) = epsilon2    (for all epsilon2 >0)
So:
$| f(1/N) + f(1/N+1) + .... + f(1/M) | < epsilon2$    (for all epsilon2 >0)
So the limit of the partial sums, goes to 0, so the serie CONVERGES.
Do you think it's ok?

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/551177/121671

It's not the same ... in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/551177/121671 says   f′′(0) exits. HERE nothing is said about f''.

Read that link carefully. It does answer your question. Read it.

it will converge i believe by considering cauchy criterion for series and the quadratic approx of f that arises from the second derivative , i can write out the proof in a few hours

answering to @TedShifrin : i'm pretty sure that link does not answer fully what I'm exposing here. Read it carefully. PLEASE REMEMBER you cannot use nothing about the second derivative here, it's not in the assumptions of the problem. Suppose it does not exists at 0.

It appears you didn't read the linked question fully as suggested by @TedShifrin. The second last sentence in the question gives a counter-example where $f''(0)$ does not exist.

@ParamanandSingh I suppose you refer to f(x)=x^(-3/2)  ( => f ''=0 not defined). YES it's an example, that suggest my demostration is good. But ... it's really good?, i.e., if a(n)>0 it's sufficient  having f(0) = f '(0)=0, to sum(a(n)) to converge?  -- thank you everyone for the feedback

The counter example is $f(x) =-x/\log x, x>0,f(0)=0$ and $f(1/n)=1/(n\log n) $. Check this by calculating derivatives.

But that function is not continous in an interval containing 0 as the enunciate says. So it is not derivable at zero neither. Not valid argument my friend!

A word of advice - while you should not take people's reputation as an assurance they are correct, when two people of high reputation tell you something that you doesn't make sense to you, you should at least stop to consider that maybe - just maybe - you may be missing something that they see. Thus it would behoove you to put additional thought to the matter before responding, and if you still disagree, to be a little less cocky in stating your issues with their remarks (though you certainly should still state them).

In this case, one can define $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \le 0$, and obtain an $f$ that has a continuous derivative on all of $\Bbb R$, and still has exactly the same $a_n = \frac1{n\log n}$. Paramanand Singh expected you to realize the behavior of $f$ on the left of $0$ could be chosen in any fashion that is convenient without affecting the counter-example at all.

Now I see. The counter example is valid. Thank you for your feedback!
